# Creating an Edge List in Stata

Tags: stata, social-networking

I have a network dataset in Stata that I need to create an edge list for. I know how to create an edge list in Python or in any scripting language, but I'm on a restricted account that doesn't have access to Python. The data is restricted so I'm not able to transfer it to a personal computer, so I'm stuck with doing this in Stata.

I want to iterate through each row the through each column. If personInNetwork isn't NULL, I want to write it to a new dataset consisting of two variables. The first variable is the id and the second variable is the network connection.

I don't know how to work with a new dataframe while keeping the relevant one in memory. I'm also not confident in iterating through rows and then columns specific to that record.

**EDIT**: Here's a toy example. Sorry for the atrocious formatting.

Here's what my data looks like now:

```
id personInNetwork1  personInNetwork2 
p1      p3                p2
p2      p1
p3      p1                p4
p4      p3
```

Here's what I need it to look like:

```
id  Connection
p1   p3
p1   p2
p2   p1
p3   p1
p3   p4
p4   p3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I think `reshape` is what you need. If you have isolates, some [extra sauce is needed](http://www.rensecorten.org/index.php/2012/07/from-adjacancy-matrix-to-edgelist-in-stata/).

If that's not it, I think it would help if you gave a toy example of the data as is and the desired output.

Comment: I added a toy example. From the Stata reshape documentation that looks like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about this topic, but you might check out  [Jennifer Earl's web page](http://jearl.faculty.arizona.edu/node/19).  Near the bottom of the page is a section entitled "Transforming Edge Lists from Pajek". It has links to a Stata command and accompanying help file.

Comment: I forgot to mark the reply, but Dimitriy had the right idea. I just needed to use the reshape command.